# JAVA Connect Four Method Incorrectly Decrements Row

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, decrement

I've written a program for connectFour that accepts:

1. user input as int (as variable selection)
2. count int (automatically calculated variable from method that returns char for R or Y to insert in multi-dimensional array)

I then wrote a method called dropChip that accepts the selection and count values as follows:

```
public static void dropChip(int selection, int count)
{   
  --selection;//make selection a human number
  if (grid[r][selection] == ' ')//while r(row) & selection is empty char
  {
     grid[r][selection] = userChip(count);//drop R or Y into grid   
  }
  else if (grid[r][selection] != ' ')//while r selection has a letter value
  {
     int x = r--;//set x to value of decremented r
     grid[x][selection] = userChip(count);//drop chip in next row of same column
  }
}
```

Here is a sample of my output in terminal:

```
| | | | | | |
| | | | | | |
| | | | | | |
| | | | |R| |
| | | |Y| | |
| | |R| | | |

Yellow player's turn.
Input a value between 1 and 6 to drop your chip:  3

| | | | | | |
| | | | | | |
| | |Y| | | |
| | | | |R| |
| | | |Y| | |
| | |R| | | |
```

Question: Why are the Y and R in column 2 (3 in human) not stacking on top of one another directly?  The value of r should be local to the method call and not set to the negative value globally, right?  What gives?

Adding the full program here in case anyone wants to look deeper:

```
import java.util.*;
//create connectFour class
public class connectFour 
{   //main method and public declarations
    public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static int selection = 0; 
    //create variable for square multidimensional array usage
    public static int y = 6;
    //build new two dimensional array of 3 rows with 3 columns
    public static char[][] grid = new char[y][y];
    public static int r = grid.length - 1;//6 as human number
    public static int c = grid[r].length - 1;//6 as human number

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("===============START PROGRAM===============\n");
        //create game prompt
        String prompt = "Welcome to the classic Connect Four game!\n\nThis program will start with the red player\nthen move to the yellow player.\n\nYou will chose a numerical value\nbetween 1 and 6 as the column to drop your chip.\n\nOnce you have dropped your chip, the program will scan\nthe columns and rows looking for a win.\nYou can win by having four chips stacked either\nhorizontally, vertically or diagonally.\n\nGood Luck!\n";
        System.out.print(prompt);

        //call the loadBlanks method with the variable of grid
        loadBlanks(grid);
        controller();
        //check4Win(grid, selection);
        System.out.println("===============END PROGRAM===============");
    }   

    public static void controller()
    {
        //set maximum number of user attempts (36 in this case)
        int maxAttempts = r * c;
        //create an empty int
        int count = 0;
        //while the count value is less than maxAttempts
        while (count < maxAttempts)
        {
        //determine which user turn it is sending count number
            userTurn(count);
            //print prompt for user disc
            System.out.print("Input a value between 1 and 6 to drop your chip:  ");
            //store user value in selection
            selection = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println();
            //send human number of selection to method that drops chip along with count value
            dropChip(selection, count);
            //print the connect four game
            printValues(grid);
            //increment value of count
            count++;
        }
    }

    public static void loadBlanks(char[][] grid)
    {//while row is < total count of rows
        for (int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++)
        {//while column in row is < total count of columns  
            for (int column = 0; column < grid[row].length; column++)
            {//fill grid with blank values
                grid[row][column] = ' ';
            }//end inner loop
        }//end outer loop
    }

    public static void dropChip(int selection, int count)
    {   
        --selection;//make selection a human number
        int x = grid.length - 1;
        if (grid[x][selection] == ' ')
        {
            grid[x][selection] = userChip(count);   
        }

        else if (grid[x][selection] == 'R' || grid[x][selection] == 'Y')//(grid[x][selection] == 'R' || grid[r][selection] == 'Y')
        {
            grid[x-1][selection] = userChip(count);
        }
    }

    //print all of the values in the array 
    public static void printValues(char[][] grid)
    {//while row is < total count of rows
        for (int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++)
        {//while column in row is < total count of columns
            for (int col = 0; col < grid[row].length; col++)
            {//print inner loop bracket
                System.out.print("|" + grid[row][col]);
            }//end inner loop
        System.out.println("|");//print outer loop bracket
        }//end outer loop
    }

    //return the value of the user chip based on turn as char
    public static char userChip(int count)
    {
        //set userColor to random value
        char userColor = ' ';

        //if the passed value of int x is evenly divisibly by 2, set char to R
        if (count % 2 == 0)
        {
            userColor = 'R';
        }//end if
        //else if the int of x modulo 2 != 0, set char to Y
        else if (count % 2 != 0)
        {
            userColor = 'Y';
        }//end elseif
        return userColor;//set value of char to userColor
    }

    //calculate user turn based on count value starting with red
    public static void userTurn(int count)
    {
        String color = " ";
        if (count % 2 == 0)
        {
            color = "Red";
        }//end if
        //else if the int of x modulo 2 != 0, set char to Y
        else if (count % 2 != 0)
        {
            color = "Yellow";
        }//end elseif
        System.out.println();//whitespace for terminal
        System.out.println(color + " player\'s turn.");//print user turn
    }
```

Comment: First, your `else` by conditions doesn't require a nested `if`

Comment: ..`r` is not declared locally to keep its value bound...and its not known what `userChip()` does

Comment: Thanks @nullpointer.  I added the full program at the bottom of my original post.  Note that I altered dropChip() to try to include a local variable for grid.length-1 (previously the globally available variable of r).  Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Any help offered is much appreciated.  I'm still stuck on this.

Comment: have a look at the answer, hope that would help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer late yesterday.  By using the global value of r, my code was decrementing that value globally any time the value of --r selection was equivalent to an R or Y character.  To solve this, I used a local for loop with x where x = grid.length-1 and decremented that value on each pass through the method.  My working example of the dropChip method is below.  I appreciate everyone's comments/help!

```
public static void dropChip(int selection, int count)
{   
    --selection;//make selection a human number
    for (int x = grid.length-1; x >= 0; --x)//set x to value of decremented r
    {
        if (grid[x][selection] == ' ')//while r(row) & selection is empty char
            {
                grid[x][selection] = userChip(count);//drop R or Y into grid  
                break; 
            }
            //else grid[x][selection] = userChip(count);//drop chip in next row of same column
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay debugging your code literally. I get to see this inside your `static void dropChip(int selection, int count)` method declaration -

```
else if (grid[x][selection] == 'R' || grid[x][selection] == 'Y') {
            grid[x - 1][selection] = userChip(count);
      }
```

this is what avoids the overlapping. Since if you find `'R'` or `'Y'` in the current block you place the new character in the `x-1` row of the grid in the same column(just above it).

In case you simply want to overwrite the existing value in the current block you can change your dropChip method to  -

```
public static void dropChip(int selection, int count) {
  --selection;
  int x = grid.length - 1;
  grid[x][selection] = userChip(count);
}
```

---

Also if you instead use

```
int x = r--;
```

then being the number of rows, would every time on reaching this statement decrement by 1. Resulting in a upward block filling in your sample output shared in the question.

---

***Edit*** - On a side note, since you are accepting only single input in your `controller` I don't see a way you want to fill up the rows above the second last in the current logic(or last in the updated logic.)

***Suggestion*** - Try and take input in terms of rows and columns to get to fill the exact block with the desired character.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response @nullpointer!  I tried updating my code with a for loop to decrement a local value for r instead of using the global variable and that worked.